# HandlerThread doesn't execute callback while a wearOS app is in background

Tags: android, wear-os, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm using HandlerThread to listen for location updates.

```
    private fun onCreate() {
        ...
        
        locationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                locationResult.lastLocation?.let { location ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "Location: ${location.latitude}, ${location.longitude}")
                    lat = location.latitude.toFloat()
                    lng = location.longitude.toFloat()
                }
            }
        }
        ...
        
        locationHandlerThread = HandlerThread("locationHandlerThread")
        locationHandlerThread.start()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        requestLocationUpdates()
    }


    private fun requestLocationUpdates() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
            )
        } else {
            val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
                interval = INTERVAL // Set the interval to 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)
                fastestInterval = INTERVAL // Set the fastest interval to 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)
                priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY

            }
            locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, locationHandlerThread.looper)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        locationHandlerThread.quit()
    }
```

The code works as expected while on foreground but when the app is switched to background the `locationHandlerThread` is in running status(from debugger) but doesn't seem to execute the `locationCallback`.

If I understand correctly, the `locationCallback` should execute even while the app is in background, right?

Comment: As of Android 10, a separate permission is needed to get location while in the background: https://developer.android.com/training/location/background